# В чем проблема? При обращении к полю экземпляра класса ничего не происходит

Tags: php

При обращении к полю экземпляра класса ничего не происходит.

**Код:**

```
<style>
li {
    display:block;
}
</style>

<?php
class Hum{
  public  $last_name;
  public  $first_name;
  public  $age;
  public  $state;
  public  $tel;    

    function  __construct($last_name,$first_name,$age,$state,$tel){
        $this->$last_name = $last_name;
        $this->$first_name = $first_name;
        $this->$age = $age;
        $this->$state = $state;
        $this->$tel = $tel;
    }

}


 $pers[0] = new Hum('qqqq','wwww',1995,'m','234234');
 $pers[1] = new Hum('aaaaa','ssss',1994,'v','45654623');
 $pers[2] = new Hum('ccccc','vvvvv',1993,'m','234234');
    echo "<hr>";
for($i=0;$i<3;$i++)
{

foreach($pers[$i] as $val){   
    echo "<ul><li>$val</li></ul>";      
}
echo "<hr>";
}
echo "<hr>";

echo $pers[1]->age; //вот
?>
```

Comment: Может ответ и не по теме конечно, но зачем делать 2 цикла? Почему просто форичем не пройтись по pers?

Comment: Это не весь код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При обращении к полю класса через `$this` у переменной не нужно указывать знак доллара:

```
    $this->$last_name = $last_name;
           ^-- // доллар не нужен
    $this->$first_name = $first_name;
           ^-- // доллар не нужен
    $this->$age = $age;
           ^-- // доллар не нужен
    $this->$state = $state;
           ^-- // доллар не нужен
    $this->$tel = $tel;
           ^-- // доллар не нужен
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, 40 минут не мог понять в чем дело)

Comment: @Xronomern пользуйся IDE. Там есть автокомплит, который поможет не делать такие ошибки и избежать других

Comment: ок, еще раз спасибо.